# How do I extract the title attribute and the text using xpath or css selector?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

From the below code i would like to fetch the text  "Manager".
The first and third line contains the word "Manager".

```
<a id="HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_a" class="level2" treenode_a="" onclick="" target="_blank" style="" title="Manager" xpath="1">
<span id="HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_ico" title="" treenode_ico="" class="button ico_close" style="width:0px;height:0px;"></span>
<span id="HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_span" class="node_name">Manager</span>
</a>
```

I tried with the following 3 xpath but none of it is giving the text "Manager".

```
(xpath ="//span[@id='HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_span']/text())
(xpath ="//*[@id=\"HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_a\"]")
(xpath ="//span[@id='HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_span']")
```

Also would like to fetch the word "Employees" from the following code.

```
<input id="HieararchyDropdownMenu" class="selectedHierarchyValue" type="text" readonly="" value="Employees" xpath="1">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? What driver are you using? XPath/CssSelector alone will not be enough to get you what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

To get the **title** Manager Try this.

```
String title=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='level2']")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(title);
```

To get the **text** manager  Try the following xpath.

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='level2' and contains(@title , 'Manager')]//span[@class='node_name']")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

To Get the **value** Employees you need to use getAttribute("attributename")

```
String idval=driver.findElement(By.id("HieararchyDropdownMenu")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(idval);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

//span[contains(text(),"Manager")]

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='HieararchyDropdownMenu']).getAttribute("value")

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can follow the printed code to run it in your IDE.

In order for you to locate the element in the DOM you can try the below.

CSS seclector:

To fetch the text manager from the title :

```
$$('[id="HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_a"]').pop().getAttribute("title");
```

To fetch the content manager :

```
$$('[id="HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_3_span"]').pop().textContent;
```

To fetch the text Employees:

CSS seclector:

```
$$('[id="HieararchyDropdownMenu"]').pop().getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: The method pop() is undefined for the type object.

Comment: @KunduK, String idval=driver.findElement(By.id("HieararchyDropdownMenu")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(idval); has given me the value "Manager".  Which i am looking for. Thanks. As Employees is a higher level and Manager and some other options are at class-level 2.    So String title=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='level2']")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(title); is giving me the next value of Manager. But i got some idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *title* **Manager** and text **Manager**, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- **Title** *Manager*:

  - Using `cssSelector`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.level2[id^='HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_']"))).getAttribute("title"));
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='level2' and starts-with(@id, 'HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_')]"))).getAttribute("title"));
    ```
- **Text** *Manager*:

  - Using `cssSelector` and `getText()`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.level2[id^='HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_'] span.node_name[id^='HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_']"))).getText());
    ```
  - Using `xpath` and `getAttribute()`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='level2' and starts-with(@id, 'HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_')]//span[@class='node_name' and starts-with(@id, 'HieararchyDropdownTreePCPPerformanceBusinessUnitIdHierarchyDropdownWidget_')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    ```